# Extracting App Version from pyproject.toml file and using it in a "docker build" command

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops, docker-image, python-poetry

This might be a dumb question, but I am currently using python poetry to improve dependency management for a git repo. The thing is, inside the pyproject.toml file there is a version for the app (ex. 1.0) and I want to somehow assign it to a variable and use that in a docker build command so that the docker image tag is the same as the app verison stated in the pyproject.toml file. So as an example, suppose the docker build command looking like: "docker build -f dockerfile -t :<1.0>" it instead should be something like this: "docker build -f dockerfile -t :<Repo_Version>", where 'Repo_Verison' is the app version extracted from the pyproject.toml file

Is something like this even possible using python poetry and Docker?

All help is appreciated, thank you.

Still new to poetry and Docker somewhat but judging from what I've seen online, this does not seem to be possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Poetry](https://python-poetry.org) [version](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#version) command has `-s` option:

> `--short (-s)`: Output the version number only.

You can use like that:

```bash
poetry install -q
IMAGE_NAME=$(poetry version | cut -d" " -f1)
IMAGE_VERSION=$(poetry version -s)
docker build -f dockerfile -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION
```